# Singleton injecting a class which persists for the lifetime of the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET web application with the following classes:

```
public class AppContext : IAppContext {
    private readonly IDataContext _dataContext;

    public AppContext(IDataContext dataContext) {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    ...
}

public class DataContext : IDataContext {
    ...
}
```

These are registered using Untity like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IAppContext, AppContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

The AppContext is a singleton and lives for the lifetime of the application, but the DataContext only lives for the lifetime of the current request.

However since the DataContext is injected within the constructor of the AppContext class it will be persisted across requests. This causes issues issues as the DataContext is disposed after the request has ended. How could I inject the DataContext within the AppContext class so that I can retrieve the correct instance?

Comment: How is `AppContext` a signelton, if it has a public constructor?

Comment: The problem you are encountering is a common pitfall, commonly referred to as [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: @ZoharPeled OP is ***not*** talking about the [Singleton Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) but about the **Singleton Lifestyle** which is a common terminology when talking about Dependency Injection and IoC Containers.

Comment: @Steven thanks, I didn't know about Singleton Liststyle.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, although it doesn't have a fix atleast this gives me a clue in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means entire design of AppContext is invalid and it should live per request as it is **now depends** on some actual request data context.

As solution, split it up into singleton class which will contain shared logic, and class with logic which depends on data context AND shared logic.

```
public class SingletonAppContext : ISingletonAppContext //as singleton
{
    //Source code where no data context needed
}

public class RequestAppContext : IRequestAppContext
{
    public RequestAppContext(ISingletonAppContext appContext, IDataContext dataContext)
    {
    }

    //Source code where data context is needed
}
```

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like this idea. I'm going to mark this as the answer but it's also worth reading the [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) article pointed out by @Steven.